# How to customize the progress loader?

Tags: android, progressdialog, loader, animated-gif

I am using a progress loader using ProgressDialog and also the component.
both are of similar type and in black color i am trying to change the loader.[image: From this loader]

Instead of this progress i need a new one looks like below one

[image: Expected progress loader]

Comment: but next time , make a better search :P

Comment: This one i am already using that one has a problem that is not looking like loader. It is getting paused for each rotations. Rather than this 360 rotated animation no other go?

Comment: Try rising Thread priority in the dialog , using this : Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

Comment: I found ultimate tutorial which covers almost all cases of such a question: http://gaudicos.blogspot.kr/2013/10/customized-progress-bar.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have use this for a load like yours

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.LoadingDialogTheme);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.loading_icon).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(InitActivity.this, R.anim.rotate360));
    }
```

/res/anim/rotate360.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="2000"
        android:repeatCount="infinite" />
</set>
```

/res/layout/loading.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:background="@color/loadingBackground">
  <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/loading_icon" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_loading"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/loading_text" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Loading"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="3dip"
    android:textColor="@color/info"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loading_icon"/>
</TextView>
```

Then what you must do is to have one frame of your gift , and use it like the loading_icon.png

Good luck with your job :)